# Create Postgres Index for OR query

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization

This is the query I want to optimize:

```
SELECT *
    FROM invited_member_events
    WHERE (user_id = '422820341791064085'
    OR inviter_user_id = '422820341791064085')
    AND guild_id = '638685268777500672';
```

I created an index for the `guild_id` column, a second index with the columns `user_id_inviter_user_id`, a third index with the `user_id` column. And it does not use them, it only uses the `guild_id` one. Do you know how can I create an index so it works with the OR condition?

[image]

as you can see, only the guild_id index is used, not the other ones.

the other indexes:
[image]

Comment: I would try with 2 indexes, on `(guild_id, user_id)` and on `(guild_id, invited_user_id)`. If they are not used, I'd retry (with those same 2 indexes) rewriting the query without the OR using UNION.

Comment: Are these 3 columns text? It would help if you provided the CREATE TABLE script - or the output of `\d invited_member_events `

Answer (score 1):

I added a `idx_invited_member_events_inviter_user_id`, and it seems to be working.

[image]

Comment: From 552 to 531 ms, not much gain.

Comment: Please don't post text as images.  Especially not images which have cropped off the most important bits.